# DotNetOpenAuth WebConsumer with Google Apps domain

Tags: oauth, openid, dotnetopenauth

How can I set the WebConsumer object to utilise the domain-level authorization ? I need this for saving the access token.

I can do this with the OpenIdRelyingParty class, by calling CreateRequest(domain), but could not find a way to obtain the access token this way.